# Algorithm to find cheaper combinations in few arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, search

I am looking for some algorithm to find cheapest combination of flights for route.

I have five arrays of flights for three-segment route. For example the route is: `Paris -> London -> Hamburg -> Moscow`. Whole route is divided into flights combinations which is not longer than two segments.

Three arrays contain one-segment flights:

```
Paris->London
    flight number 100
    flight number 200
    flight number 300
    ...etc
London->Hamburg
    flight number 101
    flight number 201
    flight number 203
    ...etc
Hamburg->Moscow
    flight number 103
    flight number 203
    flight number 303
    ...etc
```

Thwo arrays contain two-segment flight combinations:

```
Paris->London->Hamburg
    flight number 100 + flight number 101
    flight number 100 + flight number 201
    ...etc
London->Hamburg->Moscow
    flight number 101 + flight number 103
    flight number 101 + flight number 203
    ...etc
```

One two-segment combination might be cheaper than exactly same flights in two one-segment combinations, but might not.

For example it can be cheaper if I choose combination of `Paris -> London (one-segment)` + `London -> Hamburg -> Moscow (two segment)`

Or it can be cheaper if I choose combination of `Paris -> London (one segment)` + `London -> Hamburg (one segment)` + `Hamburg -> Moscow (one segment)`.

How to find all cheaper combinations considering that there is one-segment combinations and two-segment combinations with exactly same flights but with different prices?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like *Dijkstra's algorithm* for finding the shortest path on a graph.  Here the edge *lengths* of the graph are the prices on the flights.